# speed of different ways of a full-text search in XQuery (BaseX)

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.0

I am using BaseX 9.3.1 for accessing about 45.000 entries of a dictionary with about 1 million examples etc., having a full-text index as well as one for all text nodes and attributes. So far, so bad. Accessing the nodes for grammar or the meaning is quite fast. Accessing the examples, however, is very slow but only in some queries - not in all. I tried to find the reason for the following but simply did not succeed with the documentation of BaseX or some XQuery-pages etc. Maybe I just don't see the forest for the trees. Here's the issue:

```
ft:search("myDatabase", "mySearchString")
```

is very fast and responding in less then a second, whereas

```
ft:contains(db:open("myDatabase")/path/to/target/node, "mySearchString")
```

as well as

```
db:open("myDatabase")/path/to/target/node contains text "mySearchString"
```

and

```
db:open("myDatabase")/path/to/target/node[contains(./text(), "mySearchString")]
```

is so slow (>30s) and heavy that it sometimes even breaks the server.

I tried to find out the differences by changing options for stemming or the collation but it did not make a noticable difference regarding speed. `ft:contains()` is - according to the docs - an extended version of `contains text` of standard XQuery. `ft:search` seems to be a BaseX command for full-text search (see [BaseX docs](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Full-Text_Module)).

`ft:search()` is working quite well with some additional code in order to get the desired content. But that's actually more like a workaround. I need to understand why directly accessing the path is so slow even though there also is an index for it. Using `text()` instead of any version of *contain* or *match* is faster, too, but not an option for the application since the search must fetch "parts of" and not "exactly" the text content.

Any suggestion/idea/help is appreciated!

Comment: With [factbook.xml](http://files.basex.org/xml/factbook.xml) as database and with full text index switched on: `SET FTINDEX true` `CREATE DB factbook /path/to/factbook.xml` comparing the two queries `//*:name[text() contains text 'French']` and `ft:search('factbook','French')/..[local-name()='name']` that lead to the same results, both queries are almost same regarding evaluating time. No wonder: `//*:name[text() contains text 'French']` will be optimized by BaseX (v.9.2.2) to `ft:search("factbook", "French")/parent::*:name`.